# Is it possible to bind a command to a resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view model that provides a RelayCommand LoadImage.

Typically I would use a button and bind the command to this button.

However I would like to call the LoadImage command from view's codebehind (I need to do some view related stuff that must not be put into view model)

The one way I am aware is to create an event handler for the button, e.g. Button_Click.
In Button_Click I would cast DataContext to the corresponding ViewModel and use this instance to call `(DataContext as MyViewModel).LoadImage.Execute(...)`

This is odd as I need to know the view model.

What I am trying, is to bind LoadImage not to a button but to a resource in the view, so the Button_Click event just need to call FindResource with a given name and cast it to ICommand without the necessity to know the specific ViewModel.

Is this possible? The command itself is not static as it needs to know the context in what it is called.

Comment: have you tried `<Button Content="LoadImage" Command="{Binding LoadImageCommand}" Click="LoadImag_Click" />` ?

Comment: The bound command requires data from the Click-Event so I am not sure if your solution will do it.

Comment: i don't know which one get called first maybe it is based on the order

Comment: Beside the order I am unsure how I can carry context from one to another as I would rather dislike using a class member here

Comment: you could throw it to an invisible control which is also binded to your VM. so you could us the ClickEvent save the result to the control  and then your command get called and you can use the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Bill Zhangs idea of behaviours I've created a generic version which is quite control agnostic and which allows to be reused.
The required assembly is

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

I've created a Trigger action that passes the execution along to an event handler:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System;

namespace Misc
{
   public class CommandWithEventAction : TriggerAction<UIElement>
   {
      public event Func<object, object> Execute;

      public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandWithEventAction), null);
      public ICommand Command
      {
         get
         {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
         }
         set
         {
            SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
         }
      }


      public static DependencyProperty ParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Parameter", typeof(object), typeof(CommandWithEventAction), null);
      public object Parameter
      {
         get
         {
            return GetValue(ParameterProperty);
         }
         set
         {
            SetValue(ParameterProperty, value);

         }
      }

      protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
      {
         var result = Execute(Parameter);
         Command.Execute(result);
      }

   }
}
```

To avoid any logic in a custom behaviour this allows to hook up any event to an event callback followed by a command call.

XAML:

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <misc:CommandWithEventAction Command="{Binding LoadImageCommand}" Parameter="Custom data"  Execute="CommandWithEventAction_OnExecute"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    Execute
</Button>
```

This will pass the "Custom data" string boxed as object to a function called

```
CommandWithEventAction_OnExecute
```

its signature of `Func<object,object>` may use the parameter and need to return something that will then be boxed into object and passed to the `LoadImageCommand`

Comment: Marking own post as answer was guarded the last days and was only possible today. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by creating a behavior, which requires Prism referred in your project:

```
public class LoadImageBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    public public static static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof (ICommand), typeof (LoadImageBehavior));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Click += AssociatedObject_Click;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Logic...

        if(Command != null && Command.CanExecute(null))
            Command.Execute(null);

        //Logic...
    }
}
```

On Xaml:

```
    <Button>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:LoadImageBehavior Command="{Binding LoadImageCommand}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Well Behaviours are fine but what I cannot grasp is, how can I use data from my Button_Click to be fed into the behaviour?

Comment: Where does the data come from? If it is generated inside the event handler, you can pass it to the command as parameter when calling Command.Execute(...). If it comes from somewhere else, it is scenario specific, and you'd better put some code.